# Visual Studio Emulator is Offline Not Launching C++ Mobile

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, mobile, android-emulator

You might let me explain my little issue.
I switched from android studio to visual studio for mobile c++ developing.
I installed VS (visual studio) and also an Emulator for VS but all the devices i have installed are offline.
When i open them from "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" they all launch well.
But as i am trying to debug from VS IDE itself, it is only loading - see enclosed picture. If i would let it, it would load till tomorrow and i didn't find anything online similar to my issue, so i am desperately hoping you guys could help.

My System is allowing to launch the emulator and my CPU is Hyper V friendly :)
It launches when i do it from the vs android emulator
What am i doing wrong?

Launching from here works:
[image]

this is the loading that never ends :
[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? The Microsoft documentation doesn't mention anything about it

Answer (score 0):

I went into Android Device Manager, Stop emulator and right click and select factory reset. Then try again.
Worked for me.